# MetaMask: Internal JSON-RPC error with Ledger with Chrome 91

Tags: metamask, ledger-nano-s, hardware-wallets

Since Chrome 91 update, MetaMask and Ledger stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Chrome, MetaMask 5.7.1 and Ledger hardware wallets do not seem to work. [See the support forum complain thread](https://community.metamask.io/t/cant-connect-ledger-to-metamask-internal-json-rpc-error/3986/33?u=miohtama).

You can alternatively use MetaMask and Ledger with Firefox. [Here are detailed screenshot instructions on how to import your Ledger to Firefox](https://capitalgram.com/posts/metamask-internal-json-rpc-error/).